# Not throwing a validation error for an array of JSON object when it should be?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, validation

I'm posting to api/record that's suppose to catch validation errors in the JSON that I intentionally set:

**Vue Post Request**

```
this.$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'api/record',
    data: {
        emotions: [{'id': 1001, 'intensity': 20, 'new_intensity': 50}],//this.selectedEmotions,
        distortions: [{'id': 1001}],//this.selectedDistortions,
        situation: this.situation,
    }
})
```

**RecordController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'situation' => 'required',
        ]);
       
        $emotions = ['data' => $request->input('emotions')];

        $emotionsValidation = \Validator::make($emotions, [
            'data.*.id' => 'between:1,70',
            'data.*.intensity' => 'between:0,100',
            'data.*.new_intensity' => 'between:0,100'
        ]);

        if($emotionsValidation->fails()) {
             //return $validation->errors(); Gets all errors
            return response(['error' => 'There was a problem'],422);
        }
        
        $data = ['data' => $request->input('emotions')];

        $distortionsValidation = \Validator::make($data, [
            'data.*.id' => 'between:1,14',
        ]);

        if($distortionsValidation->fails()) {
             //return $validation->errors(); Gets all errors
            return response(['error' => 'There was a problem'],422);
        }
    
    //store record

    return new RecordResource($record);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my validation isn't failing with the id's that are over the `between:1,70` when it should be. How do I fix this?

I also made a [github repository for this problem](https://github.com/corbin88/sandbox/commit/1623e617b0c8f2e79a07659ed4327cfae5fafa97)

Comment: are you talking about a 'number' between 1 and 70? because that is going to get treated as a string, which means number of characters between 1 and 70 .. you have to tell it that you are trying to validate some type of number

Comment: number between 1 and 70

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-between  then read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-size   that is how it determines how those rules work

Comment: Oh wait, it looks like it's working. Just gotta try both of them.

Comment: `size` only takes 1 argument, but it isn't the rule you want ... that is just a reference if you read the `between` rule it links to `size` rule as that is where the information about how the different types are handled and how to determine the type

Comment: It was `integer|between:1,70` that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rule as

```
'integer|between:0,100'
```

it will initially get the data as a string. We need the validator to know that the data is an integer. After that, it will work.